# Getting a SIGABRT Error while rotating array

Tags: c++, arrays, rotation

I am getting a SIGABRT error! Why? This runs fine on local ide's but gives error on geeks for geeks ide. I think it is because of the array memory that I am using.

```
 #include<iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    void rotate_array(int arr[],int size,int rotate){
        for(int i=0;i<rotate;i++){
           arr[size+i]= arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[i+rotate];
        }
        for(int j=rotate;j<size+rotate;j++){
            cout<<arr[j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    int main(){
        int t=0;
        cin>>t;
        while(t>0){
            long long int N=0;
            long long int D=0;
            cin>>N >> D;
            int arr[N];
            for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            cin>>arr[i];
        }
            rotate_array(arr,N,D);
            t--;
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input?

Comment: `int arr[N];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a compile-time constant, not a runtime expression.  Use `std::vector<int> arr(N)` instead.  Second, if `N` is large enough, that non-standard syntax can blow out the stack memory.  Third, what are the input values?  If you know them, put them in the program instead of `cin` statements.  Last, "geeks..." is not a good site to copy code from, as the code almost always has bugs or is very poor.

Comment: _"I think it is because of the array memory that I am using"_ Well, this is easy to test by using `std::vector` instead of a VLA.  Chances are, if `N` can be very large, that there will be a test dataset in there designed to destroy your stack when you try using stuff like this.  An alternative to using dynamic memory is to declare a static array large enough for the largest `N`.

Comment: Also, [std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) does all of this work already.

Comment: Given an unsorted array arr[] of size N, rotate it by D elements (clockwise). This is the problem statement.

Comment: What do you mean by "clockwise"?  Is that a left rotation or a right rotation?

Comment: Clockwise is right rotation